# Check whether 2D array contains a specific 1D array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way I can check to see whether a matrix in Numpy contains a specific vector?

i.e.

```
X = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]) 

v = np.array([1, 1, 1])
```

I want to be able to test: `bool = v` in `X`. I know this doesn't work with Numpy and wonder if there is a ay to test this without obnoxious loops? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the rows with `all` then see if there's any row where all the columns have matched.

```
np.any(np.all(np.isin(X,v,True),axis=1))
```

I should mention, this is assuming that your rows are distinct and unique.

Comment: This is incorrect. Consider the example `X = np.array([[ 0,  1],[ 1,  0], [ 2,  3], [11, 11]])` and `b = np.array([11,10])`. Or have I misunderstood something here?